# Search for vector graphics in Google Images

Tags: google-search, google-image-search, search-operators

In Google Images, one can normally specify an image format, for example let's say I want PNGs; then I can type `filetype:png my search terms`.

Today, I wanted to search for some vector graphics so I tried `filetype:svg my search terms`. However, Google Images completely ignored it and returned the results I'd get for `my search terms`, without the type restriction.

So, the question is, how to search for vector graphics in Google Images? If it's not possible, what else can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google recently started indexing SVG files;

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/01/google-image-search-indexes-svg-files.html

It should be there as a 'filetype' option in the advanced images search;

http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search

---

[image]

---

This might also be useful;

[Find SVG vector images with Google Search](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/google-search-svg-image-files/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, this then renders this question obsolete, as it can now be done the way I wanted to originally -- by using `filetype:svg my search terms`.

Comment: never thought there are so little svg images in the internets...

Answer (score 0):

From the advanced search http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search , it seems the SVG Filetype is not specified, though SVGs are [indexed](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html).

So, to my knowledge I don't think it is possible via Google Images you are just going to have do a  regular search.

`http://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:svg`

Answer (score 0):

I've never needed really it, but certain day I had to do something fast and found these depots quite nice :

[www.vecteezy.com](http://www.vecteezy.com)
[vector4free.com](http://vector4free.com)

Does not answer your question, but might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

### 2019 Update:

[Google Advanced Image Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search) now includes **SVG** in the file type drop-down menu.

I have no idea when this was added, but it's a welcome addition.

[image]